# How to identify if a video is a Premiere? ...via the YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api

On YouTube we have uploads of recorded videos, live streams, and now also Premieres.

Using the [Videos: list endpoint of the YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) we can distinguish recorded videos from live streams by calling the endpoint with the `liveStreamingDetails` part. If details are given then it is a live stream. If not then it is a regular upload of a recorded video.

This approach doesn’t help me with identifying Premieres. They appear as if they were live streams. At least with the endpoint above I see no difference between live streams and Premieres.

Is there any way to check if a video is in fact a Premiere? I have the video id and want to achieve this by calling any of YouTube’s APIs.

Comment: So far, as of the [latest Revision History dated July 9, 2018](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#july-9-2018), the ["Premiere" feature](https://youtube.googleblog.com/2018/06/vidcon-2018-helping-creators-earn-more.html) was not yet added to the the documentation as this feature was launch a month before the said revision on the API side, so I think this was not yet supported as of the moment. Also, there was no update on the official documentation.

Comment: The revision history of the [YouTube Analytics and Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/revision_history) and the [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/revision_history) with their latest entries from 2018 also do not mention Premieres.Thus I assume it really is not possible yet and we will need to look for new revision entries in 2019. Thanks a lot @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 !

Comment: although this is in the Search: list endpoint and not in the Videos:list endpoint, when searching for videos you can specify the eventType parameter, which can be completed, live and upcoming
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: The way I implemented this, I look for `snippet.liveBroadcastContent`, which is either 'upcoming', 'live' or 'none'.

This way you can identify if a video is currently a premiere, or the premiere has ended and it's a regular video.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joost! Unfortunately though, the liveStreamingDetails are the same for Premieres as for live streams. So it doesn’t help me to distinguish Premieres from live stream. Or did I miss anything? What I couldn’t reproduce is the double occurrence in playlists. What api call did you use exactly? Was it an authorized request to a self-owned playlist? Was it a custom playlist or just the uploads playlist? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @analog-nico Sorry for the delay. I've been using snippet.liveBroadcastContent to identify premieres. It's either set to 'upcoming', 'live' or 'none' once it's gone live. I make a videos:list call in the API and request the 'snippet' part. Have a look at https://github.com/jschuur/learnchinese.club/blob/master/server/update.js#L137. I essentially call any video 'active' (i.e it's live to be viewed) if liveBroadcastContent is 'none'.

Comment: I've also noticed that liveStreamingDetails will contain concurrentViewers and actualStartTime while live and actualEndTime when their premiere is over. concurrentViewers stops appearing after their premiere is over too.

Comment: Thanks again Joost! I observe the same behavior for live streams. Are you actually distinguishing Premieres from live streams? Or is that a distinction you don’t need yourself?

Comment: @analog-nico I don't care about live streams specifically (neither an actual live stream, nor a video currently premiereing). The site I'm building is a list of videos for Chinese language learning and I just wanted to avoid showing videos that can't be viewed yet in full, so I don't show a video until their liveBroadcastContent is 'none'. I think their use of the word 'live' here can be misleading. My understanding is that neither the 'live' value of liveBroadcastContent nor the liveStreamingDetails block refers to actual live streaming as opposed to video premiereres with a live component.

Comment: You may find this list of the states of a videos before, during and after a premiere helpful: https://gist.github.com/jschuur/d8f1307fab765466653979cb170b5dc3. In hindsight, maybe some of the 'live' fields do also apply to non premiere related live streams and I never noticed it because the channels I follow for the site don't do actual live streams at all. All I know is I have successfully prevented videos people can't yet watch from turning up on the site via the 'liveBroadcastContent' info.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Joost! I see. We have different goals then. Sorry, I meant live stream replays. My goal is to distinguish those replays from aired Premieres. But it seems that it is really not possible as both look exactly the same in terms of the api responses. Btw awesome that you bring education to more people with your project!