# Setting video as Premiere in YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is the functionality of setting a video as a Premiere available in the API? Either on Upload or an Existing video

Setting a video as a premiere has been available for a good while now: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9080341?hl=en

It's not defined in the API documentation, and the ability to read if a video is a premiere is a bit fuzzy. Ref: [Finding premieres through Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59445665/finding-premieres-through-youtube-api/63875379#63875379) and [How to identify if a video is a Premiere? ...via the YouTube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523948/how-to-identify-if-a-video-is-a-premiere-via-the-youtube-api)

I can send the same settings to read videos as a premiere to the API, but the end result isn't a Premiere. Am I missing something?